# query Current Size on file uploading using Spring Multipart

Tags: ajax, spring, grails, file-upload

i use `org.springframework.web.multipart`  API to upload files in grails application :

what is the object that is responsable to get the current size uploaded of file :

1. -request :
2. -MultipartHttpServletRequest :
   ...or what

known that i use the following method to upload file :

```
   public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.class);
    public File uploadFile(MultipartFile file, String baseDir){
        logger.info("Uploading a file ");
        boolean successUpload = false;
        File localDestination = null;
        if(!file.isEmpty()){
            String extension = parseExtension(file.getOriginalFilename()); 
            try{
                successUpload = true ;
                String fileName = baseDir+System.nanoTime()+extension ;
                localDestination = new File(fileName);
                file.transferTo(localDestination);
                logger.info("><<SIZE MULTIPART1<>> = "+file.getSize());
            }catch(IllegalStateException ex){
                logger.info("File already replaced");
                successUpload = false;
            }catch (IOException ex) {
                successUpload = false;
            }
        }
        if(successUpload){
            return localDestination;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
```

How can i query current size uploaded , that it means : How can an action in controller return the current size on file uploading .

**UPDATE :**

i test this action when file uploading:

```
def size(){
    MultipartFile file =  ((MultipartHttpServletRequest)request).getFile('ml_files')
    render(contentType:'text/json'){
        [size:file.getSize()]
    }
}
```

known that `ml_files` is a final value used as identifier of request .

When ,i query this action with ajax , i get the following error message :

```
Cannot cast object 'org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper@6a4b6cd6' with class 

'org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper' to class 'org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest'.
```

Comment: what you are getting in output of `logger.info("><<SIZE MULTIPART1<>> = "+file.getSize());` ?

Comment: i monitor grails console.However, nothing displayed

Comment: Do you see any of the `logger.info()` strings in the console? Stick a logger.info() into the `IOException` catch block and see if that's printed.  I use code similar to yours and have no problems, so I would guess an exception is stopping the file size being printed.

Comment: Have you found the answer to this one ? Currently dealing with it yet I find it hard to reproduce.